# How to disable the "uninstall" button in Android?

Tags: java, android

In Android some system applications cannot be uninstalled.

Is there any way to configure an application so that it cannot be uninstalled by the user?
I want to hide the uninstall button in app settings, like a system app such as this: 
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not really - the only way to achieve this would be to create a custom ROM. The uninstallable apps are "system apps", or apps installed by default. Often, those are unneeded apps added there by the mobile network or the phone producer. Even those can be uninstalled though when you root your phone :)

Answer (score 1):

Your app can disable the Uninstall button by requesting Device Administration permission from the user.

The user cannot uninstall until they remove the Device Administration permission in Settings.   In this case your app's DeviceAdminReceiver will be called, giving your app a chance to react.

http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/admin/device-admin.html

Answer (score 0):

I guess you're mainly looking for a technical solution. But as there is no purely technical solution for a wider audience, you might be open for alternatives:

The phone manufacturer and the telecom provider have means to pre-install apps on a phone that cannot be uninstalled. So one way would be to get in contact with them and see if one of them is willing to cooperate with you. You'll probably need to offer them something in return.

Comment: No ! I want users cant unistall app or when them want to unistall app , my app ask password ! such as "Smart App Lock" !